# How to write an algorithm in order to calculate Euler's number

Tags: algorithm, eulers-number

How does one write an algorithm that calculates the value of e by receiving the natural number N from the user? The following equation needs to be used:

[image]

Comment: In which programing language you want to do that? what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want an algorithm description in something like pseudocode. Then your algorithm could look something like this:

```
function factorial(x)
begin
   f := 1;
   for i := x downto 1 do
      f := f*i;
   end;
   factorial := f;
end;


procedure euler(n)
begin
    e := 0;
    for i := 1 to n do
        e := e + (1/factorial(i));
    end;
    print e;
end.
```

Note that I used a [Pascal-like pseudocode variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode#Syntax) here. This method isn't the quickest, either, since there is an extra loop for every factorial from 1 to n, but I chose this way to show an intuitive way of solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution in java:

```java
float result = 1;
int fact = 1;

for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    fact *= i;
    float fraction = 1f / fact;
    result += fraction;
}
```

Comment: Very elegant, since it also implements the factorial, as well :)

Comment: Thanks. that reduced the time complexity.

Comment: I added a factorial computation to my version, too, to show the other, more time-consuming way :)